# add custom params to fullcalendar request

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm want to add a parameter named `foo` to the request that fullcalendar submits when retrieving event data. According to [the docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) this can be achieved using:

```
var getFoo() = function() {
    // implementation omitted
};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    loading: function(isLoading) {
        // CAN I SOMEHOW UPDATE foo FROM HERE?
    },
    events: {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            foo: getFoo()
        }       
    }

});
```

I want the value of the `foo` parameter to be calculated each time the calendar event data is requested, but it seems that fullcalendar only calls `getFoo()` the first time it loads, then re-uses that value for each subsequent request.

I've tried using this the `loading` event that is triggered immediately before the data is loaded, but I can't figure out how to update the `foo` paramter from within this function.

### Update

I followed the advice below and got it working with this:

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getCalendarEvents',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {

                        start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                        end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
                        foo: getFoo()
                    },
                    success: function(doc) {
                        var events = eval(doc);
                        callback(events);
                    }
                });
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [events as function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/) to create your own ajax request.

```
var getFoo() = function() {
    // implementation omitted
};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        var myFoo = getFoo();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {
                // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
                foo: myFoo
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = [];
                $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting lazyFetching to false. I'm guessing you're having this problem because fullCalendar tries to save you from unnecessary ajax requests.

[Fullcalendar doc on lazyFetching](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/)