# Retrieve Fullcalendar events from Parse.com via REST

Tags: javascript, rest, fullcalendar, parse-platform

I'm interested in using fullcalendar to display event information retrieved from a parse.com backend using REST.

Fullcalendar can retrieve JSON info as such:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

and Parse handles requests like:
https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-basic

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: abc123" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xyz789" \
--data-urlencode 'where={"start":"1262332800","end":"1265011200"}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ObjectName
```

However, fullcalendar auto adds ?start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646 to the end of destination URL.

Any advice on how to get the two to work together?  Do I format Parse's where clause differently?

Thanks for any direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by overriding the "start" and "end" parameter by sending separating Ajax Request inside the FullCalendar.

Take a look at this Similar Thread: [`7779643`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779643/add-custom-params-to-fullcalendar-request)