# Change IETF format to unix timestamp

Tags: fullcalendar

Hi is there a way to change the time format for the following snipp in fullcalendar?

```
select: function(startDate, endDate) {

        $.fancybox({
        \'width\': \'40%\',
        \'height\': \'40%\',
        \'autoScale\': true,
        \'transitionIn\': \'fade\',
        \'transitionOut\': \'fade\',
        \'type\': \'iframe\',
        \'href\': \'test.php/?start=\'+startDate+\'&end=\'+endDate,
            });

calendar.fullCalendar(\'unselect\');
        }
```

I want Start & EndDate to be a unix Timestamp.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by overriding the "start" and "end" parameter by sending separating Ajax Request inside the FullCalendar.

Take a look at this Similar Thread: [add custom params to fullcalendar request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779643/add-custom-params-to-fullcalendar-request)